# Google Apps Scripts won't ask for permission in Google Forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have written an application that requires several permissions. However, when I click through my google forms I don't get asked for these permissions. I can do the whole form to the end, but whenever I finish the form I get the error to my email (as I have the direct error messages to email feature turned on) that "permissions are required to run this script".

Does anyone know what can cause this problem?

Comment: How are you triggering the code on your form?

Comment: Yes, and it actually worked in the past. However when I modified my script (to require more permissions) and redeployed it wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: I've also cleared the permissions from my account before retrying. Also didn't work sadly.

Comment: Your answer was where I was going to direct you. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found a fix for the issue. After a change in your code you have to go to the triggers menu and press save. Just that.

Seems like a bug that I had to do this.